# how i can curl the next page with same get request php

Tags: php, curl

I have a flight booking page, I give it the data from the website, and then you enter me on the flight selection page
This is done via the code below

```
<?php
$post = [
    'username' => 'Example',
    'password' => 'Example'
];
$date = '2021-08-04';
$destination ='%20KRT';
$origin = '%20CAI';
$step = 'ChooseFromFour';
$link = <<<link
https://Example.golibe.com/index.php?action=vFlights&flights[0][departureDate]=2021-08-12&flights[0][destination]=%20CAI&flights[0][origin]=%20JED&cabin=Economy&travelers[0]=ADT&returnTicket=&dateVariants=exact&step=ChooseFromFour
link;

$headers = [
    "Origin: http://Example-ex.com/",
    'Scheme: https',

];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $post['username'] . ":" . $post['password']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

When choosing a flight, I have to go to the payment page and it will automatically transfer me to it
But I want to fetch this page as well, I mean that when I click on a button, it does not take me to the original site, but also takes this page and displays it to me without using the code again

Because I don't think it makes sense that I'm pulling every page I want to access
And if you ask, this is legal or not (yes, it is legal, this is only because I do not have the authority to modify the style files, but it is legal and also my account that I log into)

Comment: And what's your question about this? What keeps you from fetching any other page? Maybe you want to use any library that hides all these cURL options?

Comment: the question is , i curled a page and there's links inside i need when i click to any link don't redirect to this link i need to get it in same page